# XMPPFramework can i use XEP-0065 for video chat

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

I used [ObjC XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) for organize chat(1-1, room) in my application.
We need implement live video chat. I know, that [Jingle](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/jingle/) is the best solution for this, but it doesnt't implemented  in XMPPFramework.

But, there is XEP-0065 implementation, and it says:

> The bytestream can be either direct (peer-to-peer), The typical transport protocol used is TCP, although UDP can optionally be supported as well.

So, i have an idea  - transfer video byte stream through XEP-0065

Can i do this?

---

I know, i'm just searching more easier way to do that. I see, that Jingle have a lot of XEPs - xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/jingle - is XEP-0166 is all i need OR i must implement other XEPs(e.g. 0167, 0176) ?

Comment: Of course you can transfer video with bytestreams, but this will cause a signification loss of interoperability and it may not be a trivial task.

Comment: I'm just finding easy way how to organize iOS XMPP video chat...

Comment: @IgorKhomenko Have you got any idea or way to implement video chat using XMPP framework in iOS? Also you can reply your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/q/24490393/952440.

Comment: @sunilz Yes, we already did this http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-videochat-ios

Comment: @IgorKhomenko Thanks. But I want to implement it with XMPP framework.

Answer (score 2):

For video chat, the cleanest way is to implement XMPP Jingle protocol on the client side.

You need to have a look at the specification:
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html

To my knowledge it is not implemented in XMPPFramework, so you will have to add it.