# XEP-0166: Jingle protocol implementation for voice/video chat in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I have already implemented chat with text message using XMPP framework for iOS. But, now I want to implement voice/video chat using XMPP framework in iOS. So, anybody know about how to implement XEP-0166: Jingle Protocol with available XMPP framework in iOS/Objective-C? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anybody give me the reason of down vote and close vote for this question?

Comment: hey sunil z , any success on this ?I am also stucked with the same problem. Any suggestions on how did u proceeded?

Comment: @iPhoneDev No, I did not get it. I am searching for it. Also you can check update for this question here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xmppframework/2Mztozd9PEc

Comment: @iPhoneDev Also someone has suggested to use class file from following link https://github.com/phono/PhonoSDK/tree/master/modules/phono-ios/XMPPFramework-phono/Extensions/XEP-0166, but I have not checked it.

Comment: @iPhoneDev If you have any suggestion/solution, please share with us.

Comment: @sunilz have you implemented video calling through xmpp+webRTC?

Answer (score 1):

http://oriolrius.cat/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Oreilly.XMPP.The.Definitive.Guide.May.2009.pdf

Refer This book regarding XMPPFramework. In this book all things are described regarding all fetchers provided by XMPP like one to one messaging, file sharing, voice call, video call and etc.

In this book how to send stanzas to server and client are described in detail.

hope this book will help u.